# What Event is Triggered With DataGridView NumericUpDown?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, event-handling, numericupdown

### Goal

To capture the event that is triggered whenever a user clicks on the "Up" or "Down" arrow of a DataGridView's Numeric Up down.

[image: DataGridView's NumericUpDown]

---

### Code Used For Numeric Up Down

This code generates a NumericUpDown column that I can add to my DataGridView.

```
Public Class NumericUpDownColumnRight
Inherits DataGridViewColumn

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New(New NumericUpDownRightCell())
End Sub

Public Overrides Property CellTemplate() As DataGridViewCell
    Get
        Return MyBase.CellTemplate
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As DataGridViewCell)
        ' Ensure that the cell used for the template is a NumericUpDownCell.
        If Not (value Is Nothing) AndAlso Not value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(GetType(NumericUpDownRightCell)) Then
            Throw New InvalidCastException("Must be a NumericUpDown")
        End If
        MyBase.CellTemplate = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class

Public Class NumericUpDownRightCell
    Inherits DataGridViewTextBoxCell

Private _Minimum As Integer = 0
Private _Maximum As Integer = 25

Public Property Minimum As Integer
    Get
        Return _Minimum
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        _Minimum = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Maximum As Integer
    Get
        Return _Maximum
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        _Maximum = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New()
    '
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub InitializeEditingControl(ByVal rowIndex As Integer, ByVal initialFormattedValue As Object, ByVal dataGridViewCellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle)
    ' Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value.
    MyBase.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle)
    Dim ctl As NumericUpDownRightEditingControl = CType(DataGridView.EditingControl, NumericUpDownRightEditingControl)
    ctl.Minimum = Minimum
    ctl.Maximum = Maximum
    Dim CurrentValue As Decimal = 0
    If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(Me.Value) Then
        If Decimal.TryParse(Me.Value.ToString, CurrentValue) Then
            ctl.Value = CurrentValue
        End If
    Else
        ctl.Value = 0
    End If
End Sub

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property EditType() As Type
    Get
        ' Return the type of the editing contol that NumericUpDownCell uses.
        Return GetType(NumericUpDownRightEditingControl)
    End Get
End Property
Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ValueType() As Type
    Get
        ' Return the type of the value that NumericUpDownCell contains.
        Return GetType(Decimal)
    End Get
End Property
Public Overrides ReadOnly Property DefaultNewRowValue() As Object
    Get
        ' Use as the current default value.
        Return Nothing
    End Get
End Property
End Class

Class NumericUpDownRightEditingControl
    Inherits NumericUpDown
    Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl

Private dataGridViewControl As DataGridView
Private valueIsChanged As Boolean = False
Private rowIndexNum As Integer

Public Sub New()
    Me.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Left
    Me.UpDownAlign = System.Windows.Forms.LeftRightAlignment.Right
End Sub

Public Property EditingControlFormattedValue() As Object Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue
    Get
        Return Me.Value.ToString("#.##")
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Object)
        If TypeOf value Is Decimal Then
            Me.Value = Decimal.Parse(CStr(value))
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Public Function GetEditingControlFormattedValue(ByVal context As DataGridViewDataErrorContexts) As Object _
    Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue
    Return Me.Value.ToString() ' Me.Value.ToString("#.##")
End Function

Public Sub ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(ByVal dataGridViewCellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle) _
    Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl
    Me.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font
    Me.ForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor
    Me.BackColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor
End Sub

Public Property EditingControlRowIndex() As Integer _
    Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex
    Get
        Return rowIndexNum
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        rowIndexNum = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Function EditingControlWantsInputKey(ByVal key As Keys, ByVal dataGridViewWantsInputKey As Boolean) As Boolean _
    Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey
    ' Let the NumericUpDown handle the keys listed.
    Select Case key And Keys.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Left, Keys.Up, Keys.Down, Keys.Right, _
            Keys.Home, Keys.End, Keys.PageDown, Keys.PageUp
            Return True
        Case Else
            Return False
    End Select
End Function

Public Sub PrepareEditingControlForEdit(ByVal selectAll As Boolean) _
    Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit
    ' No preparation needs to be done.
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange() As Boolean Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property

Public Property EditingControlDataGridView() As DataGridView Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlDataGridView
    Get
        Return dataGridViewControl
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As DataGridView)
        dataGridViewControl = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property EditingControlValueChanged() As Boolean Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlValueChanged
    Get
        Return valueIsChanged
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        valueIsChanged = value
    End Set
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property EditingControlCursor() As Cursor Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingPanelCursor
    Get
        Return MyBase.Cursor
    End Get
End Property

Protected Overrides Sub OnValueChanged(ByVal eventargs As EventArgs)
    ' Notify the DataGridView that the contents of the cell have changed.
    valueIsChanged = True
    Me.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(True)
    MyBase.OnValueChanged(eventargs)
End Sub
End Class
```

---

### Problem

Whenever I click on a cell, I usually handle the `DataGridView1.CellContentClick` event to deal with whatever is going on. Except, this only executes when I click on the cell, but doesn't realize when I'm clicking up or down. How can I achieve the handling of the "Up" and "Down" events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative. It's not exactly what I'm asking for but I end up getting the value anyway... I handle the CellLeave event, which then I go locate the value of the numeric up down's cell.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellLeave(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellLeave
    If e.ColumnIndex = DataGridView1.Columns("ColNud").Index AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim NudValue = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value
    End If
End Sub
```